# Removing Kernel Message during Rpi boot-up with a custom image

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi2, buildroot

I have successfully created a custom kernel for raspberry pi 2 model B using buildroot, it is working as it should, but I don't want to see the kernel message and also the Rpi logo on the top left corner. Is there a way to change the boot splash screen to some custom image, Thank You all in Advance

Comment: It is not specific to rapsberry pi 2 model B, you can remove boot message exactly the same way as for others platforms.

Comment: @Mali: I tried that I was able to remove the logs with wheezy on pi 2 but the logo is still there, if there is a document or something that you might guide me to, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `logo.nologo` to remove logo and `quiet` to remove kernel messages at the end of cmdline.txt